# Network problem after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04!

Tags: wireless, networking

As title suggests, I upgrade to 14.04. After that browser informed:

*...can't find the server at "host name"...*

So the name server seems not to work. How should I fix the problem?

Comment: What's the output of `nslookup google.com`?

Comment: output is    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Could you post the output of `nm-tool`?

Comment: What do you want to know? for dns it says
dns: 193.229.0.40
dns: 193.168.0.1

Last one is gw not dns

Comment: Does `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` work?

Comment: Yes this command works well but browser gives error!

Comment: Could you also try `nslookup google.com 193.229.0.40` and `nslookup google.com 193.168.0.1` so we can be sure it is an issue with Ubuntu's internal DNS server or not. Also, did you assign the DNS servers yourself or are you using DHCP (automatic)?

Comment: 1. one works. 2 one doesn't.
I am using DHCP (automatic). Wlan did work previously fine and my other windows7 pc's network works fine.

Comment: nslookup claims that default server is 127.0.0.1 and it should be 193.229.0.40 (I got this from other PC which uses also dhcp.)

Comment: System settings/network says that dns is 193.229.0.40 192.168.0.1

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu uses a local DNS server that caches DNS queries and forwards uncached queries to your DNS servers. I've seen some people that are having trouble with it. You can try to set your DNS servers manually in network manager (and then only set the working one) or add the working one in top of `/etc/resolv.conf` (you can't edit this file directly, you should add it to `resolv.conf`'s header template).

Comment: No the file resolv.conf says *domain elisa-laajakaista.fi search elisa-laajakaista.fi nameserver 127.0.0.1*

Comment: In file is also comment *#generated by NetworkManager*.    Should I replace the nameserver address 127.0.0.1 with 193.229.0.40

Comment: Yes, remember to edit as root (`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`) and try if it's working. Please note that your `resolv.conf` will be overwritten at reboot so you need to make it permanent if it's working.

Comment: Yes, it works. I.e. browser works fine. How to make it permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
   ```
2. Add the following line to the top of the file:

   ```
   nameserver 193.229.0.40
   ```
3. Save the file:

   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>
4. Restart your network (or reboot your pc):

   ```
   sudo service networking restart
   ```

Comment: Before making this change, I restarted the computer and tried to load some web page. Everything worked fine. So the information has not disappeared.

Comment: That's strange, but cool that it's working now.

Comment: Before making this permanent change, I tried to restart my network (as stated above). Result was *stop: job failed while stopping start: job is already running networking*